# Amazon Cloudwatch CPU utilization returning no data points

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

Tried to use the AWS CLI and boto (Amazon Python SDK) to get CPU utilisation metrics, but so far the calls have not returned any data points at all.

My boto call is like so:

```
endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
startTime = endTime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)    

metrics = cloudwatchConn.get_metric_statistics(60, startTime, endTime,
                                               'CPUUtilization',
                                               'AWS/EC2', 'Average')
```

If I use the AWS web console to manually view the CPU utilization graphs, I can see that the data is there, but my API calls are not returning anything for some reason.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

This doesn't answer the question, but as a workaround, if I use UTC start and end times, while utilising the *dimensions* parameter and filtering by instance ID, I get data points.

So I am just going to get all my instance IDs and get the CPU utilization metric manually for each one.

Comment: Did you try using ``datetime.datetime.utcnow()`` rather than ``datetime.datetime.now()``?

Comment: Yes I have, no luck.

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried your code (using utcnow) and it worked for me. The only other thing I could of was that your metrics are delayed > 10 minutes so nothing is showing up.  What happens if you change 10 -> 60?

Comment: Still nothing. Do I need to have detailed monitoring enabled on my instances, because I don't?

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  Detailed just adds finer granularity.  How long as the instance been running?  Can you see any data for the instance in the Cloudwatch web console?

Comment: A little over two hours now. Yes I can see sane looking CPU usage graphs in the web console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78369/discussion-between-freshquiz-and-garnaat).